# Eigenvalue assignment via state feedback: existence proof

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, ds.dynamical-systems, oc.optimization-and-control

Consider the linear time invariant system:
$$\tag{1}\label{eq1}
\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t) + Bu(t), \ \ x(0)=x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n,
$$
where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. Let $p_M(s)$ denote the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.
The following result is classic in linear control theory$^1$.

> **Theorem 1**. Let $q(s)$ be any monic real polynomial of degree $n$. If the system \eqref{eq1} is [controllable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllability), then there exists a matrix $K\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ such that
> $$
> p_{A+BK}(s) = q(s).
> $$

The standard proof of this result is constructive and makes use of a canonical form of  \eqref{eq1}, known as the controller canonical form.

> **My question.** Is there any known (not necessarily constructive) proof of Theorem 1 that does not use the controller canonical form?

---

$^1$ See e.g. Chapter 7 of T. Kailath. *Linear systems*. Prentice-Hall, 1980.